# Syntax error: unexpected token '$current_user' Line 97

Tags: php

```
            <!-->This is the new code I am trying to add<!-->
            <?php if $current_user = 'test' { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cimulus.atlassian.net/s/fe43f6fc5a628824d47590ead0fc6aee-T/en_US-iikkpb/64014/28/1.4.24/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector.js?locale=en-US&collectorId=2a7a4da1"></script>
            }
```

I am trying to add an html script that displays a button only for users "test" but I keep getting this syntax error on line 97 which is this line. I don't really understand what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php if (TEST_MODE) { ?>
```

Comment: <?php if $current_user = 'test' { ?> should be             <?php if ($current_user == 'test') { ?>

Comment: To check a value you need to use == :) `if ($current_user == 'test') `

Comment: Two errors on this line: `<php if ($current_user == 'test') { ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few errors at the bottom: missing brackets on your `if`, you have used `=` instead of `==` and the final closing brace is outside of `<?php` tags...

```
<!-- This is the new code I am trying to add -->
<?php if ($current_user == 'test') { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cimulus.atlassian.net/s/fe43f6fc5a628824d47590ead0fc6aee-T/en_US-iikkpb/64014/28/1.4.24/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector.js?locale=en-US&collectorId=2a7a4da1"></script>
<?php } ?>
```